# Kafka consumer group not reading from a single partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka topic with 3 partitions. I have a consumer group consuming from the said topic and I notice that 2 of 3 partitions are being consumed in real-time (lag 0), whereas 1 partition is simply not consumed at all.

How do I go about diagnosing this issue?

Appreciate inputs/comments.

Comment: is consumer group has concurrency value  3?If so then each thread will consume in each topic

Comment: How many consumers do you have ?

Comment: Just the one consumer. (said consumer group)

Comment: The data in that partition may be expired? Maybe try a new group id and consume from latest offset. A similar issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/187#issuecomment-299043280

Answer (score 3):

To diagnose the issue you can use kafka-tool.

Following command shows partition, current offset, log-end-offset and lag client_id for particular group

`./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafkaAddres:9092 --group yourGroupId --describe`

Output will be something like that:

```sh
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
input           0          3               4               1               consumer-1-f64504ca-f514-4cef-95fa-1652702d4504 /192.168.160.1  consumer-1
input           1          3               3               0               consumer-1-f64504ca-f514-4cef-95fa-1652702d4504 /192.168.160.1  consumer-1
input           2          3               3               0               consumer-1-f64504ca-f514-4cef-95fa-1652702d4504 /192.168.160.1  consumer-1
```

Above output shows, that only one consumer is connected and read from all partitions. At time of checking for partitions 0 lag was 1.

**NOTICE**: Some of partitions might be *empty*

Comment: I did do this, and I found that the consumer group simply does rebalance properly. Is there a way to force rebalance? currently, I am out of ideas. Simply restarting the consumer triggers a rebalance. But the rebalance is of no use because the same issue continues (i.e one of the partitions is never assigned)

Comment: @irrelevantUser, Why do you need rebalance? Does `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` show, that there is permanent lag for a group for particular partition?

Comment: Exactly. There is a lag for just the one partition. I tried restarting the consumer group (kafka consumer process) and although I see "consumer group is rebalancing" message in `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` while the process restart happens, the rebalance does not solve the issue. Once the Kafka consumer process restarts, it continues to read only from two partitions, and the other problematic partition continues to lag.

Comment: @irrelevantUser, does `CURRENT-OFFSET` for _lag_ partition moves forward or it doesn't change?

Comment: It does not change. Only for one of the three partitions I have.

Comment: @irrelevantUser, Could you add your sample code? Is situation is same if you use `kafka-console-consumer.sh` tool?

Comment: It is issue with one consumer group only. I am able to add new consumer groups and they work just fine. 
I am guessing the 'problematic' consumer group has got some corrupted metadata.

Comment: @irrelevantUser, does `CONSUMER-ID` is same for all three partitions?

Answer (score 0):

For your new partitions to reflect, you need to configure the `metadata.max.age.ms` property for your consumer.

The metadata contains the partitions for a given topic and which brokers are leader for those partitions etc. This is fetched by the consumer when the first `poll` occurs and is next fetched after the timeout or some error occurs.

By default the timeout is `300000ms = 5 minutes`, so until 5 minutes your consumer cannot know the new partitions.

Metadata is refreshed either when there is an error or the metadata max age is reached.

```
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG,"60000");
```

So try setting it to some thing low.